# Proving that no periodic orbits exist for f(x) = x + q (mod 1)

Tags: dynamical-systems

We have the following map:
$$f(x) = x + q \quad\text{(mod 1)}$$
where $q$ is irrational. I would like to show that this map has no periodic fixed points, for any period $k$. This amounts to showing that
$$f^k(x_0) = x_0$$
is never true for any fixed $x_0$. The hint of my textbook asserts that
$$f^k(x_0) = x_0 + kq = x_0 \quad \text{(mod 1)}$$
Since $q$ is irrational, this amounts to saying that $kq = n$, for some integer $n$, which is clearly not possible. I am a little stuck how they got to their expression for $f^k$, though. Am I missing something obvious? It looks like, in general, it would have a nasty expansion.

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration,
$q$ is added.

After $k$ iterations,
$kq$ has been added.

The $\bmod 1$ can be done
after every iteration
or just at the end -
the result will be the same.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to raise the entire expression $(x+q)$ to various powers - forgot to just take the function of the function. D'oh! Thanks.